# Language Change with respect to Location

Tags: android

I have a scenario wherein my Application should automatically select the language basing on the region. For example, if my application is used in Germany, then the entire application's labels and Alerts should be changed into German! Is there any API or Jar which may sort out my problem? Please help me out and thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want this?  It's counter to the Android model where its based on the system locale set by the user.  It also makes no sense-  if I go on vacation to Germany I don't want my app to switch to German, because I don't speak it.  If you mean you want to use the system locale, you just need to use string resources everywhere and add values-XX folders for each language you wish to support with a strings.xml file defining the strings in that language.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gabe! And I've mentioned clearly that if "My" application is to work somewhere out of my country whose language I don't know and there is no way to support the application with strings.xml of that language, and if that's the case, then is there any language API or Jar that I can deploy in my application.